# Dealing with constructors when using inherited classes

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, composition, default-constructor

I am new to classes, and I am trying to understand how constructors work when used one in another by inherited classes.
So in my project I have 2 classes. For instance one being postalService:

```
class postalService {
private:
    string address;
    Date date //I used another class Date (composition)
public:
    postalService();
    postalService(string a, int b, int c, int d);
    postalService(const postalService& p);
    ~postalService();
}
```

With constructors:

```
postalService::postalService():address(""), date(){
}
postalService::postalService(string a, int b, int c, int d):address(a), date(b,c,d){
}
postalService::postalService(const postalService& p) {
}
postalService::~postalService(){
}
```

And then another class being Letter, which is inherited by class postalService:

```
class letter : public postalService {
private:
    bool registered_shipment;
    string sender;
public:
    letter();
    letter(postalService& a, bool b, string c);
    letter(const letter& p);
    ~letter();
```

With constructors:

```
letter::letter():postalService(), registered_shipment(false), sender("") { 
}
letter::letter(const letter& p):postalService(p), registered_shipment(p.registered_shipment), sender(p.sender) { 
}
letter::letter(postalService& a, bool b, string c):postalService(a), registered_shipment(b), sender(c){ 
}
letter::~letter(){  
}
```

Now, when i try this code below if I create an object of postalService (not with default constructor) named `service` and try to include it in my object letter using the following constructor: `letter::letter(postalService& a, bool b, string c):postalService(a), registered_shipment(b), sender(c){ 
}` :

```
letter my_letter(service, true, "John Smith");
```

Every inherited variable is empty (not the same as in `service` object). 
I am trying to understand what is going on here. I hope I made my self clear and I apologize for such stretched out question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok. But if I do, why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The `postalService` copy-constructor, which you invoke in the specific `letter` constructor, does nothing. That means it will not set anything.
2. The `letter` class already ***is a*** `postalService` class, that means you don't create a separate instance of the `postalService` class and pass it as an argument. Because then the inherited field will be empty (you never set them in the `letter` instance).

If you want to set the `postalService` member variables, you need to create an appropriate constructor in the `letter` class, and in its initializer list call the appropriate constructor in the `postalService` class.

Comment: So if i wanted to fill all data at once, it would be ok if I written  constructor like this: 
    letter:letter(string add, date d, bool reg_ship, string sen): postalService(add, d), registred_shipment(reg_ship), sender(sen) {...} ?
I did the other way around becouse i tried to avoid many variables in constructor.
Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The inherited variables are empty because the copy contructor of the class postalService doesn't make any copy:
`postalService::postalService(const postalService& p) {
}`

You should replace it with:
`postalService::postalService(const postalService& p) : address(p.address), date(p.date) {
}`

If your class Date has some pointers as members, check also that the Date copy constructor is well defined (deep copy).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know how I missed that one out.